# subtracting rows using diff()

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe similar to this:

```
name  group val
cici   a    3
john   b    2
john   a    1
john   c    5
ian    a    2
ian    a    3
```

I am trying to 1) group by name 2) calculate the difference among vals.
the returned column should be:

```
name  group val    delta
    cici   a    3   0
    john   b    2   0
    john   a    1   -1 
    john   c    5   3
    ian    a    2   0
    ian    a    3   1
```

I used diff() to calculate this, however, for john, I am trying to get b-b, a-b, c-b, but when I use diff(), I got b-b, a-b, c-a...is there anyway I could use the diff to count their difference with the first row in the group?
my code:

```
df.groupby('name')['val'].transform('diff')
```

Anyway to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not need diff

```
df['dif'] = df['val'] - \
                 df.groupby('name')['val'].transform('first')
 
df
Out[222]: 
   name group  val  dif
0  cici     a    3    0
1  john     b    2    0
2  john     a    1   -1
3  john     c    5    3
4   ian     a    2    0
5   ian     a    3    1
```

Comment: The return should be 0, 0, -1, 3, 0, 1 instead of 0, 0, -2, 0, 1,1.

Comment: I used diff() wihtout transform, I still got the same results i had before. For John, it's still b-b, a-b, c-a

Comment: @totolow try with the update , you need the first